# in firebase angular I fetch data with snapshotchanges subscribe but whenever I update the date in another function Subscribe call two times

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my angular application one of my components I run the below code in the ngOnInit() function.

```
const current_date = new Date();
        this.afs.collection('/layouts', ref => ref.where('store_uid', '==', this.current_store_uid).orderBy('start_date', 'desc')).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
            this.current_layout_data = []
            data.forEach((docs: any) => {
                const startDate = docs.payload.doc.data().start_date.toDate()
                const endDate = docs.payload.doc.data().end_date.toDate()
                if (startDate <= current_date && endDate > current_date) {
                    this.current_layout_data.push(docs.payload.doc.data())
                }
            })
            this.layoutData()
        });
```

In the above code, I run the query of Firebase to get the data of layout and apply some conditions.
I use snapshotchanges() and subscribe because I want to display data in real-time in HTML to display the user.

After that, I update the data on the button click I run the below function to update the data in Firebase

```
async trigger_from_publish_btn(data) {
        try {
            const start_date = new Date(data.start_date.replace(/\-/g, '/'));
            const end_date = new Date(data.end_date.replace(/\-/g, '/'));
    
            start_date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Set to 00:00:00
            end_date.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // Set to 23:59:59.999
            console.log("trigger_from_publish_btn", data);
    
            await this.afs.doc('/layouts/' + this.current_template_id).update({
                uid: data.uid,
                layout_type: data.layout_type,
                layout_json: data.layout_json_saved,
                include_header_checkbox: data.include_header_checkbox,
                start_date: start_date,
                end_date: end_date,
                actual_start_date: new Date(data.actual_start_date.replace(/\-/g, '/')),
                actual_end_date: new Date(data.actual_end_date.replace(/\-/g, '/')),
                header_text: data.header_text,
                terms: data.terms,
                layout_json_saved: data.layout_json_saved,
                layout_json_temp: data.layout_json_temp,
                page1_type: data.page1_type,
                page1_url: data.page1_url,
                page2_type: data.page2_type,
                page2_url: data.page2_url,
                page3_type: data.page3_type,
                page3_url: data.page3_url,
                page4_type: data.page4_type,
                page4_url: data.page4_url,
                page5_type: data.page5_type,
                page5_url: data.page5_url,
                is_publish: data.is_publish,
            });
    
            console.log('Data updated successfully');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error updating data:', error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I update the data in firebase subscribe query run two times and that's why layoutData() function call two time.

Would anyone know what I've done wrong?

I unsubscribed all subscribers in the ngOnDestoy() method but Still getting the same issue.

I want to run the subscriber query only one time after updating the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for previous subscriptions and destroy them using ngOnDestroy(), check if your components is reinitialising that is whenever you click the update button is it triggering layoutData() again (you can find this by putting breakpoints on this.layoutData() and when you click on Update button).Remember to destroy subscriptions after the component is not used.
Or you can provide more info on you component behind code so that i can have a look and find out whats causing the issue but before that try the above.

Comment: I created one from in component and after that whenever component is initialize then I get the data from firebase database using subscribe. When component initialize that time work fine, but when I enter changed data that time I want to create the new collection in database but It create the two collection insted of one.

I'm not destroy the subscriber because this is one component. I'm not changing the component.